# Error with sending money

Tags: error

I connected the wallet to my test site, enter the amount for the test payment and click the button, after which a window is displayed and confirmation where it says "That the confirmation period has expired" how to fix it?

Phantom wallet

My code

```
<script>
    var wallet;
    const lamports_per_sol = solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
    async function connectWallet() {
if (window.solana) {
    try {
        wallet = await window.solana.connect();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    window.solana.on(
        "connect",
        () => (
            document.getElementById("connect_button").innerText = "Connected",
            document.getElementById("walletMessage").style.display = "none"
        )
    );
} else if (window.Trust) {
    try {
        wallet = new Trust.Web3Provider();
        await wallet.enable();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
} else {
    console.log("No wallet provider detected.");
}
```

}

```
    async function sendButtonClick() {
      const receiverAddress = "5AZbfDTE4ZrdBpyZrWdzB5u8VeZQyRiKVBXzmcKCKUzJ"

      const quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value
      if (quantity != null && quantity != 0) {
        document.getElementById("status_p").text = "Status";
        document.getElementById("status_p").innerText = "Sending " + quantity + " SOL to " + ellipsizeAddress(receiverAddress) + " account address";
        await signInTransactionAndSendMoney(receiverAddress, quantity)
      } else {
        document.getElementById("status_p").text = "Status";
        document.getElementById("status_p").innerText = "Amount must be more than 0!"
      }

    }

    function ellipsizeAddress(str) {
      if (str.length > 35) {
        return str.substr(0, 8) + '...' + str.substr(str.length - 8, str.length);
      }
      return str;
    }

    function signInTransactionAndSendMoney(destPubkeyStr, quantity) {
      (async () => {
        const network = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
        const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(network);
        const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();

        try {
          const lamports = quantity * lamports_per_sol;

          console.log("starting sendMoney");
          const destPubkey = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(destPubkeyStr);
          const walletAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(
            wallet.publicKey
          );
          console.log("wallet data size", walletAccountInfo?.data.length);

          const receiverAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(
            destPubkey
          );
          console.log("receiver data size", receiverAccountInfo?.data.length);

          const instruction = solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
            toPubkey: destPubkey,
            lamports,
          });
          let trans = await setWalletTransaction(instruction, connection);

          let signature = await signAndSendTransaction(
            wallet,
            trans,
            connection
          );

        } catch (e) {
          console.warn("Failed", e);
        }

      })();

      async function setWalletTransaction(instruction, connection) {
        const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
        transaction.add(instruction);
        transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
        let hash = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
        console.log("blockhash", hash);
        transaction.recentBlockhash = hash.blockhash;
        return transaction;
      }

      async function signAndSendTransaction(wallet, transaction, connection) {
        const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(
          transaction
        );
        await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
        return signature;
      }
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your wallet is connected to the same cluster as your application.

If your wallet is connected to Mainnet and your app to Testnet it will cause issues like these.

Comment: I dont enable testnet, i have 5$ on my phantom wallet , and i try to send this 5$ to my friend, and this error

Comment: i try send this money from my site

Comment: Well, your code states you are connected to Devnet (`const network = "https://api.devnet.solana.com"`) so if you want to send it on Mainnet, make sure you update the endpoint in your code.

Comment: What network for not dev

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
index.html:140  Failed Error: failed to get info about account HPFpsvyxaY2fzYxXsp7L3vQi5J4hKbhMSoryYrQHjqP7: Error: 403 :  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 403, "message":"Access forbidden, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com."}, "id": "4c044eae-6cc6-4afa-9d69-ab7266f3dd2a" } 

    at Connection.getAccountInfo (connection.ts:2546:13)
    at async index.html:116:41

and i have error

Comment: You need to connect to 'mainnet' but using the endpoint you used in your latest comment does not allow usage from a web browser.

You can sign up for a free RPC at a provider like Helius, QuickNode, or Chainstack and use that.

Comment: Devnet is back up. Please try this again. I will close this if it was just a bug with Devnet

Comment: @JacobCreech it feels like the issue consists of 2 things: code connecting to devnet (which was down) but also wallet connected to a different cluster (presumably mainnet).